# ActiveRecord like reflection in swift

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

I was wondering how to accomplish an active record like (not with core data, but with rest, but this part I don't think will be an issue).

The issue its that don't understand well the reflection in swift, and my goal its to have a base class called Collection like (just prototype not really working code here):

```
public class Collection
{
    public var Id: String
    public static func Name () -> String
    {
       // accomplished but not with static method
    }

    public static func Find () -> [ChildClass] // the child class how can I obtain dynamically?
    {
       // restful things
       return [ChildClass, ChildClass, ...] // rest result maped from json
    }

    public static func FindById (id : String) {}

    // also Save && Delete methods
}
```

This kind of things I accomplish in c# with [WSD-Data](https://github.com/norman784/wsd-data) exactly in this [class](https://github.com/norman784/wsd-data/blob/master/Collection.cs)

So the usage maybe will:

```
public class User : Collection
{
   public var FirstName: String
   public var LastName: String
}
```

or c# like (dunno if this can be done in swift)

```
public class User : Collection<User> // we pass user as reference class c# like
{
   public var FirstName: String
   public var LastName: String
}
```

I hear also other alternatives to get this done, because don't know so well swift and the way that things are done with it.

Comment: You may want to look at [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle), a subclass-able model object designed for working with APIs.

Comment: I'll check it out, but also for learn will be cool to make it work...